# How to rewind time on just the main character?

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a 2D sidescrolling game and I want the character to be able to rewind time on him if he messes up. I don't want anything else to change, just the main character's position. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Snapshot his state on every frame, like position and orientation, into a big array. Some of this will depend on clever game design so that simply "rewinding" still "makes sense". For example, if his rewound-position now overlaps a moving bad guy or something, what should happen. (Also somewhere Jonathan Blow has a video where he explains the Braid engine, might be good to watch.)

Comment: This is still the same basic question as the one you originally asked, and still a duplicate of the older question; the answers are fundamentally the same except with the qualification that you only need to apply them to one entity in the world.